# Why is the split method still returning a string

Tags: javascript

I understand that javascript's split() method should take a string and split it into an array based on the parameter(s) passed in the method.

I have run the following in the console:

```
var sen = 'I love javascript';
sen.split(' ');
console.log(typeof(sen));
```

So split(' ') should split the string based on whitespace and return an array with 3 strings.

However the console returns the typeof as "string" rather than "object"

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Read [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference). What *is* the result of [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)?

Comment: I have read documentation, or I wouldn't ask here.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split I see that split should result in an array of strings. running typeof on an array should return object shouldn't it.

Comment: Keyword: *returns* (the assumption in the question is wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because split doesn't change sen.
The returnvalue of

```
sen.split(' ');
```

would be an array.
Try:

```
var sen = 'I love javascript';
var arr = sen.split(' ');
console.log(typeof(arr));
```

Comment: so the problem was that I needed to store the result of sen.split(' ') in a variable. Got it!

Comment: @HelloWorld - it would be more correct to say that the split function doesn't modify the original value

Comment: @jasonscript && jhinzmann - If either of you have time would you mind explaining? I understand the split function is used to split a string into an array. Why does it not modify the original value (or the data type for that matter) unless it is stored in a new variable?